# How to find the sum of the asynchronous data?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am trying to find total duration of all mp4 files in a folder. but i am unable to find the sum.

```
 const fs = require('fs');
const ffprobe= require('ffprobe');
const ffprobeStatic = require('ffprobe-static');
let sum=0;
const files=fs.readdirSync('./');
files.forEach(file=>{
    ffprobe(file,{ path: ffprobeStatic.path },(err,info)=>{
      if(err) console.log(err);
      sum+=file.streams[0].duration;
   });


console.log(sum)// 0;
```

Comment: It seems you are only only adding to the sum if there was an error in the call to ffprobe...

Comment: @fredrik: No he's not... Look again...

Answer (score 1):

You only want to call `console.log(sum);` after every asynchronous operation has completed.

Thus, when you're processing the files, keep a running total of how many asynchronous operations have been completed (`filesProcessedSoFar` below), and compare that to the total number of asynchronous operations expected (which, in this case, would be the same as `files.length`, since you're performing one async operation for each file).  If the comparison shows that those two values are equal, you know all jobs have finished, and can call your `console.log(sum);` code at that point.

Example:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const ffprobe= require('ffprobe');
const ffprobeStatic = require('ffprobe-static');
let sum=0;
const files=fs.readdirSync('./');

// let's keep track of how many of the asynchronous jobs have finished, so we can call our printSum() function only when the last one finishes
let filesProcessedSoFar = 0;

files.forEach(file=>{
    ffprobe(file,{ path: ffprobeStatic.path },(err,info)=>{
      if(err) console.log(err);
      sum+=file.streams[0].duration;

      // if all files have been processed, it's time to print the sum
      filesProcessedSoFar++;
      if (filesProcessedSoFar == files.length) {
          printSum();
      }
   });


function printSum() {
    console.log(sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked the code thoroughly, but the first impression tells me it's a problem of async output. You are using `console.log()` synchronously while your output is calculated later.

So that is the reason you see output as 0. All your `sum` related logic should be implemented in the same flow .i.e.

```
 sum+=file.streams[0].duration; 
 console.log(sum);// after this line
```